# Insert a Javascript value into struts2 param

Tags: javascript, struts2

My question I'm sure has a very simple answer but I can't find it. I save cookies with Javascript in one page and in other page I get the value of the cookie and save it in a Javascript variable.

```
<script>
   var ucMenu = getCookie('userCookieSL');
</script>
```

Then I need to insert the value saved in ucMenu into the param userCookiesSL

```
<s:a action="favorites">
   <s:param name="userCookiesSL"/>
</s:a>
```

I have tried with a hidden variable but it doesn't work.

```
<input type="hidden" id="auxUserCookiesSL" name="auxUserCookiesSL" />
<script>
   var ucMenu = getCookie('userCookieSL');
   document.getElementById('auxUserCookiesSL').value = ucMenu;
</script>
<s:a action="favorites">
   <s:param name="userCookiesSL" value="auxUserCookiesSL"/>                                          
</s:a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it with other form.

```
<s:form id="frmFavoritos" action="favoritos" theme="simple">
   <input type="hidden" name="userCookieSL" id="userCookieSL"/>
   <script>
      var ucMenu = getCookie('userCookieSL');
      document.getElementById('userCookieSL').value = ucMenu;
   </script>
   <img src="../Imagenes/Administracion/bRTdpoqi9.png" title="Аñadir a Favoritos" 
      style="box-shadow:  0px 0px 0px;" onclick=" enviarFavoritos();"/>
</s:form>
<script>
   function enviarFavoritos(){
      document.getElementById('frmFavoritos').submit();
   }
</script>
```